# Prawn - Zoom out contents so that it fits in one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation, prawn

I have a dynamic PDF report which gives monthly report of our database. I am using Prawn to generate the PDF report.

The monthly report can contain maximum of 90 rows (maximum 3 per day). There can also be days with no record. So, the number of rows in a monthly report is highly dynamic.

The client needs the report in a single page PDF. They dont care if the font size becomes very small or the row height is really small. But the contents should fit in a single page.

They have shown examples of PDF that are generated using their previous application. In those, it seems that they are creating the table with a fixed font size and row height etc. and they are somehow zooming out so that the PDF has some whitespace in the right side of the page, but it fits in a single page.

Something like this:
[image: Something like this]

Is there a way to achieve this in Prawn?

Answer (score 1):

The needed page layout can be easily achieved with [PD4ML's](http://pd4ml.com) fitPageVertically() API call - but PD4ML approach differs from Prawn quite significantly.

With PD4ML you have to generate an HTML document with report data/table (not that tricky to do) and after that pass it to PD4ML for a converting to PDF.

PD4ML in Ruby scenario can be launched as a standalone converter application.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can build a fixed size table for print with option:

overflow: :shrink_to_fit

in table cells. That will shrink to a smaller font automatically.

2. given the number of rows to be print, you can dynamically adjust tables row heights

see: http://prawnpdf.org/prawn-table-manual.pdf